# Cplex using Java - adding a constant number into IloNumExpr

Tags: java, cplex

I am trying to add a constant value into `IloNumExpr` but `obj.addTerm()` does not accept just a `double` type and i can't find a function to add `double` values to `IloNumExpr`.

For example:

if my objective is `min p + some variables`. how can i add that, p of type `double`, to that `IloLinearNumExpr obj = cplex.linearNumExpr()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This has no effect on the solver / solutions (assuming we are talking about objective offsets!) and one could skip it and post-process this by re-adding the offset to the final objective-value.

If one is interested to have this in the model (for reasons), there is always the possibility of adding an extra-variable to the objective and fixing it (e.g. by setting lower_bound = upper_bound = offset).

But it seems cplex has some dedicated functionality for this according to the documentation:

- see [IloObjective](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloObjective.html)
- and [setConstant](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloObjective.html#setConstant(double))

There are different approaches to setting up the objective, but you will need to:

- create a `IloObjective` object (linked to the model)
- call above function to set the constant
- add your linear-term

Never have used the java-interface i expect it to look similar to (code probably broken):

```
IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();

double constant = 1.0;          // your objective offset constant
IloNumExpr obj_expr = ...       // your linear objective

IloObjective obj = cplex.addMinimize();
obj.setConstant(constant);
obj.setExpr(obj_expr);
```